# Which among these are function pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I came across this question in one of my quiz.

Which is(are) valid function pointer declaration(s) below ? Select all that apply.

```
A、void* f(int);
B、int (*f)();
C、void (*f(int , void(*)(int)))(int);
D、void (*(*f)(int))();
```

for me, I would choose all that has a pair of brackets in the end. But I'm not sure about the C and D.

Comment: Try [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/).

Comment: If you are not sure, just test it.

Comment: I must admit that whenever I use function pointers (and it's years since I don't), I google their syntax. It looks a bit obscure to me. I'd prefer **function_pointer** to be a keyword which appeared at every function pointer declaration. But that's just me.

Comment: A is not pointer to function, B is a pointer to function, in C there is pointer to function but it is complicated, D also pointer to function

Comment: This should be closed because there is no real question, it is something like a quiz.

Answer (score 2):

per the "right-left" rule on http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html

```
A、void* f(int);  f is a function taking an int para that returns a pointer to void
B、int (*f)();  f is a pointer to a function that takes no (as it's c++) para and returns int
C、void (*f(int , void(*)(int)))(int); f is a function  that takes an int and a function pointer as parameters, returning a pointer to a function that takes an int as para and returns void
D、void (*(*f)(int))(); f is a pointer to a function that takes an int as para and returns a pointer to a function that take no para and returns void.
```

so B and D are your answer

Comment: Did you use the rule you gave, or link larsmans gave?

Comment: i used the right-left rule. i didn't know cdecl.org before but now it looks a great webpage